# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'qr_code' still i installed getting error like this

Tags: python, django

Getting an error like this again even though I installed the app: `module not found "qr_code"`

[image: error screenshot]

Comment: How did you install this module? Which commands did you execute?

Comment: have you add the module in your INSTALLED_APPS ?

Comment: pip install qrcode -Tmpod

Comment: yes ,that's also completed

Answer (score 1):

You are installing the wrong module. It is [`django-qr-code`](https://pypi.org/project/django-qr-code), not just [`qrcode`](https://pypi.org/project/qrcode) ;)

Install that via pip and keep the Django config the same; everything should be good.

Comment: I am working this also but but even I am getting like that

Comment: Can you show more code please? How are you configuring this Django module?